# VB.Net "me" equivalent in Linq expression

Tags: vb.net, linq, lambda

In a linq query, I need to somehow pass a reference to the object being created during a linq query, to another class that is being created within that same query...I know this question isnt't clear, so see example below.

```
 public class class1
      public class class2
           private _class1 as class1
           public property OtherProperty1 as int

           Public sub new(cls1 as class1)
                _class1 = cls1
           End Sub
      End class
      public property Property1 as int
      public property Property2 as class2
 End Class

 Dim e as List(of class1) = (From row as datarow in dataTable.Rows
                             Select New class1 with {
                                  .Property1 = row.Item("Property1"),
                                  .Property2 = new class2(<<< ME >>>) with {
                                      .OtherProperty1 = row.Item("OtherProperty1")
                                  }
                             }).ToList()
```

So, in the code above, where "<<< ME >>>" is located, I need to pass into the new class2 object a reference to the class1 object being created.

One alternative that I know I can use is to create the class1 object during this query, skipping the references to the class2 object.  Then, later on, use a foreach loop on all of the class1 objects and a new linq query to populate the missing class2 objects...it will work, but it isn't ideal.  I'd like to populate everything at once, rather than doing parts of it at a time.

--EDIT--
Ideally, I wouldn't have to change the existing classes because it could have unwanted side effects in other parts of the code...If I have to make changes though, I would be open to doing something where I am creating a new constructor or property, as suggested in some answers.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't know to much about VB, but I think you are using property initializers, so you can use a block of code creating the instance first, then set the property using the created instance, then return the instance.

Comment: As your code is now, you are missing property declarations in `class1` of which you are accessing in the Linq query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something similar. In class1

```
Public Class class1
    Public ReadOnly Property this As class1
        Get
            Return Me
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Then you can just call `.this`

```
Dim e as List(of class1) = (From row as datarow in dataTable.Rows
                         Select New class1 with {
                              .Property1 = row.Item("Property1"),
                              .Property2 = new class2(.this) with {
                                  .OtherProperty1 = row.Item("OtherProperty1")
                              }
                         }).ToList()
```

I've not tested this

Comment: It feels a little bit hackish, like something I used to do back in my javascript days, but it works and I don't have to re-write a bunch of code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well as the constructor of Class2 needs an instance of Class1, can't you can just create it?

```
Dim myClass1 As New class1

 Dim e as List(of class1) = (From row as datarow in dataTable.Rows
                             Select New class1 with {
                                  .Property1 = row.Item("Property1"),
                                  .Property2 = new class2(myClass1) with {
                                      .OtherProperty1 = row.Item("OtherProperty1")
                                  }
                             }).ToList()
```

Comment: I think that OP wants to inject the same instance of `class1` being created. Not some other instance.

Comment: Yacoub is correct.  I need a reference to the parent class1 instance .

Answer (score 0):

You could use constructors:

```
Class class1
   Public Property Property1 As Object
   Public Property Property2 As class2

   Public Sub New(Property1 As Object, OtherProperty1 As Object)
      Me.Property1 = Property1
      Property2 = new class2(Me, OtherProperty1)
   End Sub
End Class

Class class2
   Private otherClass As class1

   Public Property OtherProperty1 As Object

   Public Sub New(class1 As class1, OtherProperty1 As Object)
      otherClass = class1
      Me.OtherProperty1 = OtherProperty1
   End Sub
End Class

Dim e as List(of class1) = (From row as datarow in dataTable.Rows
                            Select New class1(
                               row.Item("Property1"),
                               row.Item("OtherProperty1")
                           )).ToList()
```

Comment: Class1 does not have/need a reference to class2.  Class1 is a parent to class2 and the reason I am having this issue is because the class2 constructor requires a reference to the class1 parent.  Why they didn't build it in to begin with...I don't know, but now I am stuck with this setup.

Comment: @LucasBailey What do you mean "is a parent to"? Like `class2` inherits from `class1`? Your code sets `Property2` of `class1` to a `class2` reference. I'm just following the code you've shown so far. It would help if you showed the definitions of `class1` and `class2`.

Comment: No, not inherits...as in...if I were declaring a standalone instance of class1 and class2...I would Dim class1 as new class1() Dim class2 as new class1.class2()...probably should have put that in the code...I will edit the original question

Comment: I just added the class definitions...so as you can see, the stupid part that I am struggling with is that the previous developer decided that he wanted some properties in class1 that were calculations of all the other properties in class1, class2, class3...etc (about 4 other classes), where whenever a child property changes...the calculated properties in class 1 would be re-calculated.  That is why I the child class needs a reference to the parent class, so that the parent can execute the recalculate code after a property change.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not an expert in *VB* and this probably can be done better but you could do something like this:

```
Dim e As List(Of Class1) = (From row As DataRow In dataTable.Rows
                            Select Create(row)).ToList()

Function Create(row As DataRow) As Class1
    Dim result As Class1 = New Class1 With
    {.Property1 = row.Item("Property1")}

    result.Property2 = New Class2(result) With
    {.OtherProperty1 = row.Item("OtherProperty1")}
    Return result
End Function
```

I tried to do it without the extra function but I don't if it's possible in *VB*.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge you cannot reference the instance of an object when instantiating the object because the object does not exist yet. 
i.e. you can't do this:

```
Public Class foo
    Public Sub New(bar As foo)
    End Sub
End Class

Dim bar As New foo(bar) ' Null Reference Exception
```

Your source code in the question is not a complete example as you are accessing undefined properties in `class1` and you cannot reference `class2` without qualifying it under `class1`. As such I have taken some liberties to add the missing declarations to your code. I have added the `.toString()` function on class2 just to show that the `_class1` is being referenced. Please take note that I am using VB 14 in my code below; not that it's needed for the core of this example, but using `$""` is much cleaner than `String.Format()`

Here is my version of your code:

```
Public Class class1
    Public Property Property1 As Object
    Public Property Property2 As class2
    Public Class class2
        Private _class1 As class1

        Public Property OtherProperty1 As Int32

        Public Sub New(cls1 As class1)
            _class1 = cls1
        End Sub

        Public Property Property1 As Int32

        Public Overrides Function toString() As String
            Return $"{_class1.Property1.ToString} success"
        End Function
    End Class
End Class
```

And here is my solution:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()
dt.Columns.AddRange({New DataColumn("Property1"), New DataColumn("OtherProperty1")})
dt.Rows.Add({"foobar", 123I})

Dim CreateNewClass1 = Function(x As DataRow)
                          Dim cls1 As New class1 With {.Property1 = x.Item("Property1")}
                          cls1.Property2 = New class1.class2(cls1) With {
                            .OtherProperty1 = x.Item("OtherProperty1")}
                          Return cls1
                      End Function

Dim e As List(Of class1) = (From row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                            Select CreateNewClass1(row)).ToList()

e.ForEach(Sub(x) Console.WriteLine($"{x.ToString}
class1.property1 = {x.Property1.ToString} 
class1.Property2 = {x.Property2.toString} 
class2.otherProperty1 = {x.Property2.OtherProperty1}"))

Console.ReadLine()
```